# Swappiness set to 100 but swap partition still not being used

Tags: swap

```
free -h
```

outputs

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.8G        1.9G        875M        354M        1.0G        1.6G
Swap:          7.4G          0B        7.4G
```

I set the swappiness to 100 using `sysctl` but the swap partition isn't being used at all.

I've also tried turning the swap off, making it swap again and then turning swap on again using `swapoff`, `mkswap` and `swapon` but it still isn't being used at all (0B).

Comment: Open up 10 copies of chrome and in each chrome window open up 10 tabs of youtube videos. Swap will probably increase before you get to 10 windows x 10 tabs.

Comment: But swappiness is already 100, and I'm only trying to enable swap because it's crashed on me twice before when I ran out of physical memory. I've tried opening up a few tabs but it only increases usage of physical memory and swap memory is still untouched.

Comment: Awww. Well your `free -h` example doesn't show memory close to being full which would mean swap would be invoked...

Comment: so I tried opening up even more, 30 tabs of youtube videos and it's finally using swap space thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix